# User input for size of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

If we cannot take user input for size of an array then how come the following program is running fine?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int size, key = -1, i;
scanf("%d", &size);
int A[size];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    if(A[0] > A[1])
        key = 0;
    else if(A[size-1] < A[size-2])
        key = size-1;
    else{
    for(i = 1; i <= size-2; i++)
    {
        if((A[i] > A[i+1])|| (A[i] < A[i-1]))
        key = i;
    }
}
printf("The key is %d at position %d\n", A[key], key);
return 0;}
```

Comment: `If we cannot take user input for an array` what do you mean? You can.

Comment: sorry .....user input for size of an array

Comment: But you can do this.

Comment: I have heard we have to use malloc function for that

Comment: Perhaps OP read some old book or tutorial which didn't cover C99 ?

Comment: Read about VLA, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: You can: [VLA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)s

Comment: Here GCC documentation on the matter https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Variable-Length Array` feature in `C` programming language standards has changed over time before `C99` it wasn't supported, in `C99` it became a mandatory feature, in current standard `C11`  it became a conditional feature :

> > > C99 introduced several new features, many of which had already been implemented as extensions in several compilers:
> >
> > - variable-length arrays(although subsequently relegated in C11 to a conditional feature which implementations are not required to support)

So it depends on the compiler you are using, I think the compiler you are using supports this feature.
check this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99